# Box-muller Gaussian random number generator & plot his

Tags: python, random, generator, physics

I am trying to write code in python using the Box-Muller equations, but I do not know how to start!

This is the example I am trying to solve:

> - A peak observed at 900 keV shows a FWHM of 2 keV. Using a Gaussian sampling method listed below, generate 15,000 counts corresponding to the 900 keV peak and save the sampled energies.
> - Create and plot a histogram with a bin width of 0.2 keV and compare with the Gaussian function with the same peak area.
> - Using a data analysis software, try a Gaussian fit to the Monte Carlo data and see the result is close enough to the peak model.
>
> **Box-Muller Gaussian sampling method:**
>   [ Note, the two sampled variable y1, y2 below are for the unit Gaussian distribution (i.e. mu=0,segma=1).
>
> ```
> y1 = (-2 ln r1)^1/2  * cos(2pi*r2)
> y2 = (-2 ln r1)^1/2 * sin(2pi*r2)
>
>    (r1, r2: random numbers)}
> ```

Any suggestions?

*** Update ***

I am getting an error msg:

> g1 = BoxMuller(v) NameError: name 'v' is not defined

The code used is:

```
import random    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import numpy as np

def BoxMuller():    
    r1 = np.random.randn(15000)*10    
    r2 = np.random.randn(15000)    
    a = 2.0 * np.pi * r2        
    v = np.sqrt( -2.0*np.log(1.0 - r1)) * np.sin(a)        
    u = np.sqrt( -2.0*np.log(1.0 - r1)) * np.cos(a)

g1 = BoxMuller(v)
g2 = BoxMuller(u)
q = 900.0 + g1*2.0
k = 900.0 + g2*2.0
plt.hist(q, k)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a way too broad question; receiving from-scratch-to-end answers to such home assignment like questions is very unlikely here. I'd suggest you see the help page on what topics to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Your formulas for Box-Muller are [incorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box–Muller_transform#Basic_form).

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is simple implementation to start and tinker with

```
import math
import random

def BoxMuller():
    r1 = random.random()
    r2 = random.random()

    a  = 2.0 * math.pi * r1
    v  = math.sqrt( -2.0*math.log(1.0 - r2))

    return (v * math.sin(a), v * math.cos(a))


g1, g2 = BoxMuller()

q = 900.0 + g1*2.0
...
```

UPDATE

Apparently, there is FWHM given, not std.dev. To get sigma, one have to divide FWHM by `2*sqrt(2*log(2))` ~ 2.355. So sampling code should be

```
FWHM = 2.0
q = 900.0 + g1 * FWHM/2.355
```

Comment: @James : Please add the code to the question with an introduction that you refer to this answer. Here in the comment it is hard to see the indentations. You seem to have a non-standard understanding how a function is written and how it works. Note that `r1` can take the value 0, but never the value 1, which is why `(1-r1)` was used in the answer.

Comment: @James I just copied it back to buffer and run with python 3.6 - works for me. Are you sure you kept the indentation? It is important in python

Comment: For the code I added above I kept the indentation but still have the same error msg!!  Also, I am using Python 3.6.5.

Comment: @James try this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hmNE-sh5QOwyWoUffPRIykXnIrFxzhy4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @James You're welcome. I've noticed another thing - you're given FWHM, not sigma. To get sigma, you have to divide by `2*math.sqrt(2*math.log(2))`, about 2.35. https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Leo/Stats2_3.html

Comment: @James btw, if you're satisfied with the solution, please accept the answer